# Access violation error with injected dll C++

Tags: c++, windows

So recently I made my own dll injector to be able to debug my other app by injecting a debug dll in it; Using c++/cli for the interface and c++ for the code.

I tested the same code I used on this project on a *C++ console app project* and it worked without any problems.

The injection occurs inside the `Init.cpp` file, which essentially gets the provided dll path under the form of `C:\\user\\documents\\debug.dll` and checks if it exists. After that it gets the process id by passing the name, in this case `myotherapp.exe`, as a parameter. If successful it then get's the Handle to the process and store's it in `g.h_process`, it continues by allocating readable/writable memory in the process and then writing to this memory the path of the dll and finally use's `LoadLibraryA` to load the dll inside the process.

`Init.cpp`:

```cpp
void Injector::Init(void)
{
    Inject::Checks((char*)g.dll_path, g.procName);//checking for dll validity
}

bool Injector::Inject::Checks(char* dll_path, PCSTR procName)
{
    if (!Utils::file_exists(dll_path))
        return Utils::error("File does not exist.");
    Utils::successInput("Prepared DLL for injection");

    Utils::getProcId(procName, g.proc_id);
    if (!g.proc_id) {
        return Utils::error("Could not find specified process.");
    }

    g.h_process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, g.proc_id);
    if (!g.h_process) {
        return  Utils::error("Failed to open a handle to process");
    }

    g.allocatedMemory = VirtualAllocEx(g.h_process, nullptr, MAX_PATH, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);//mem_reserver reserve memory then commit memory to be able to write to that memory

    Allocate(g.allocatedMemory, dll_path);

    Llib();

    Release(dll_path, g.allocatedMemory);
    return 0;
}

bool Injector::Inject::Allocate(void* allocatedMemory, char* dll_path)
{
    if (!allocatedMemory)
        return Utils::error("Failed to allocate memory");

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(g.h_process, g.allocatedMemory, g.dll_path, MAX_PATH, nullptr))
        return Utils::error("Failed to write process");
    return true;
}

bool Injector::Inject::Llib() {
    HANDLE h_thread = CreateRemoteThread(g.h_process, nullptr, NULL, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(LoadLibraryA), g.allocatedMemory, NULL, nullptr);
    if (!h_thread)
        return Utils::error("Failed to create remote thread");
    return true;
}

bool Injector::Inject::Release(PCSTR dll_path, void* allocatedMemory)
{
    CloseHandle(g.h_process);
    VirtualFreeEx(g.h_process, allocatedMemory, NULL, MEM_RELEASE);
    return true;
}
```

The `g.debug` is just a flag which tells us if the console is enabled or not. found in the [globals.hpp](https://github.com/AlexSimpler/FrameInject/blob/master/shared/Utilities/variables/globals.hpp) which just contains global variables.
You can also check the `Utils` namespace [here](https://github.com/AlexSimpler/FrameInject/blob/master/src/Utilities/utility.cpp).

**The error:**

The problem I'm experiencing here is whenever I inject my DLL into the process, my injector works fine with no errors but when I attach vs to the process I want to inject **to** I get an `Access Violation` error with the process exiting with an error code.

I don't understand, I can't see where I am accessing invalid memory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a [mre] in the question itself without external links

Comment: `error is occuring in my opinion` debug your application and find out where the error actually occurs.

Comment: @AlanBirtles `my injector works fine with no errors but when I attach vs to the process I want to inject to I get an Access Violation error with the process exiting with an error code`, updated

Comment: Have you tried debugging the process that is crashing?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, the only thing I get is a crash with an access violation error just after calling the LLIB function in my injector.

Comment: If you run in a debugger you should get a stack trace

Comment: @AlanBirtles Where can I see the stack trace?. Because whenever I attach to the process I get this message: `The program '[22188] tester.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.` and then it crashes and its detached.

Comment: Are you attaching before the program crashes?

Comment: @AlanBirtles  Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213175/discussion-between-alex-and-alan-birtles).

Comment: How do you pass the path argument to LoadLibraryA in the target process?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I allocate memory inside the process and then I write to this memory my DLL path and then I call `LoadLibraryA` on this memory with `g.allocatedMemory` which is the address of the allocated memory.

Comment: Ah, I see. That might actually work. -- So `char` in your control process is ANSI (as opposed to Unicode)?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I believe so.

Comment: we need to see the code from your DLL and from the target process

Comment: @GuidedHacking The DLL is just a normal visual-studio generated dll with a messagebox printing "HelloWorld" (`MessageBoxA`) when loaded inside the target process. And my target process is a C++/cli generated app with just one button, which I added myself. I can still send you the code but I think that would be useless because I just added 1/2 lines of code inside the DLL and C++/CLI generated templates.